# How to build Kinect DK viewer example with cmake file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, azurekinect

I want to test the viewer example from the new Kinect DK sdk. I try to compile the project manually by adding headers and libs (opengl, imgui...) but I still have links errors. I try to compile the Cmake file, provided by the SDK, with cmake-gui (I just provided path to the CMakeList.txt and the path of the folder where to build the project) but when I generate the builded project I still have the same dependencies errors.

[image]

Is there another way of building the project with the cmake file directly in Visual Studio (2019)?

Comment: Have you checked the [build docs](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/blob/develop/docs/building.md)? If there are any errors, you need to be more specific, i.e.: What does your CMakeLists.txt look like? How did you include the libraries, that give you errors and so on. Did you remember to [update init external dependencies](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/blob/develop/docs/dependencies.md) via `git submodule update --init --recursive`?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to build from the ZIP file. You need to clone the repo. From building.md:

> If you need to build from source, you have to clone the repository instead of downloading the Zip file to ensure all the submodule dependencies in place.